# Multi-column index combined with unique index efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, multiple-columns

We have a table that has multiple columns, and we have a `UNIQUE` index on one of our columns (lets call it `GBID`), and we have another column (lets call it `flag`) that has no indicies. This table can be quite large and we query `WHERE gbid IN () AND flag = 1` **a lot**, we occasionally query `WHERE gbid = "XXX"` and rarely query `WHERE flag = 1`.

Which is more efficient when it comes to indicies:

1. Have `gbid` as `UNIQUE` and `flag` with no index
2. Have `gbid` as `UNIQUE` and have a multi column index for `(gbid, flag)`
3. Have `gbid` as `UNIQUE` and have a multi column index for `(flag, gbid)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the % of rows with flag=1, and on how many rows you select (how many gbid's you have in the `IN` clause).

- If it is low (1-2%) and you are selecting a lot of gbid's, options 2 and 3 might be faster (I think option 3 will be better in that case).
- If you have a more even distribution of flag values having it in the index won't make a difference.

If you want to be sure you should benchmark it with a sample of real data.